# How to create database with code first approach with initializer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to create database if is not exists in Entity framework core.
We could use initializer with code first approach in Entity Framework using Database Initialization Strategies without `migrations` as in the link below

- `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`
- `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`
- `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

How to do this in Entity Framework Core and .Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this, is by adding the following code in your Startup.cs - Configure method

```
public void Configure(... ) 
{
  //....
  var context = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<YourDbContext>();

  context.Database.Migrate();

 // To Delete
 context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
}
```

Applies any pending migrations for the context to the database. Will create the database 
if it does not already exist.

Alternative, there's another pre-condition that you can use:

```
if(context.Database.EnsureCreated()) { // your code here...}
```